# Confusion when creating ODBC Conecction string

Tags: c#, odbc

I'm trying to create a connection string in order to work with a ODBC in a C# console application.

[image]

```
var dbConnection = new OdbcConnection("DRIVER={Relativity Client};ServerName=192.168.1.5;Port=21060;Database=Analyzar;UID=USER;PWD=PASSWORD;");
```

Of course user and password have the right values. But I keep getting this error

***ERROR [08S01] [Liant][Relativity][Client][Client LNA]Client cannot access the data source because RelServer is not running at the specified port number. Contact your system administrator for assistance.***

Can any one help me with this plz?

Comment: If that error message is correct, you need to change the port number to the correct one, or fix the problem on the server side.

Comment: What happens if you try: `ServerName=192.168.1.5:21060` and don't use the port?

Comment: @ErikPhilips I get this. ERROR [S1000] [Liant][Relativity][Client][Client LNA]This data source is missing the 'ServerName=' entry. Please contact your system administrator for assistance.

Comment: @Guillelon with that error I would then look at Robert Harveys Comment.

Answer (score 0):

Hi just found your question while looking for something myself which I have now solved.
Here is the Connection String you are looking for using your example.

```
var dbConnection = new OdbcConnection("DRIVER={Relativity Client};ServerName=192.168.1.5.21060;ServerDSN=Analyzar;UID=USER;PWD=PASSWORD;");
```